# Cookies disappear after redirect

Tags: node.js, angular, http, redirect, cookies

I have:

1) A client side app that has its own domain: http://client.com

2) A server side app that has a separate domain: http://server.com

Now,

the scenario is:

1) Opening http://client.com/home in the browser, which displays an HTML page.

2) http://client.com/home redirects to http://server.com/login

3) http://server.com/login stores a cookie 'auth' and sends a redirect instruction to http://client.com/welcome

Response:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 104
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>
> Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2019 10:47:11 GMT
>
> Location: http://client.com/welcome
>
> Set-Cookie: auth=1479da80-197c-11e9-ba74-59606594e2fb; Path=/
>
> Vary: Accept
>
> X-Powered-By: Express

4) The browser receives the response, which does contain the cookie 'auth'

5) The browser redirects itself to http://client.com/welcome

6) 'auth' cookie is sent to http://client.com/welcome

Request:

> Cookie: auth=1479da80-197c-11e9-ba74-59606594e2fb

7) http://client.com/welcome returns HTML but does not return the cookie 'auth'

[image]

[image]

8) http://client.com/welcome makes an AJAX request to http://server.com/data (CORS enabled), but the cookie 'auth' is not sent

9) http://server.com/data doesn't recognize the user because there is no cookie

The client side is an angular app hosted by Node.js

**Edit:**

As suggested, I've added to the response of server.com:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

but nothing has been changed.

Relevant client side code:

```
const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'withCredentials': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    });

this.httpClient.get<any>(this.baseUrl + "data", { headers: headerOptions }).subscribe((res) => {
```

Comment: `6) 'auth' cookie is sent to http://client.com/welcome` it must be `Set-Cookie: ...` in order for it to be returned in response as `Cookie`. Can you post the request/response headers of the full flow?

Comment: @marekful - done

Comment: Elaborate step 3, please. How exactly `server.com` is setting cookies. Show full headers.

Comment: @Styx - I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description of what is happening does not seem right.

- http://server.com/login stores a cookie 'auth' and sends a redirect instruction to http://client.com/welcome
- 'auth' cookie is sent to http://client.com/welcome

That is not (or at least should not be) what is happening. When the browser requests http://server.com/login and gets back in the response a `Set-Cookie` header, the cookie is set on and restricted to the `server.com` domain, even if the response is a redirect. If you are seeing the 'auth' cookie sent to `client.com` then that is a cookie that `client.com` previously set.

Anyway, it seems that what you really care about is

- http://client.com/welcome makes an AJAX request to http://server.com/data (CORS enabled), but the cookie 'auth' is not sent

There are a bunch of reasons this can happen.

- [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You mentioned it was CORS enabled, but for the sake of others reading this, you must have the following CORS headers set on `server.com`

  - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client.com`
  - `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
- Note that you cannot get away with using a wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when you are sending credentials. Also note that the origin has to be an exact match, including scheme (http or https). In practice, what servers generally do is read the `Origin` header of the request, check it against a white list, and if it allowed, copy the `Origin` header value from the request to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.
- You must set `xhr.withCredentials = true` in your XHR request. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) for more details.)

Then after you have done all that, you have one other hurdle in your way. Because you are on `client.com` and trying to send a cookie to `server.com`, the `server.com` cookie is considered a "third-party" cookie. AFAIK all the major browsers have a setting that blocks third-party cookies for privacy, because they are most often used by trackers to gather marketing data for advertising. I believe most of them block third-party cookies by default, but I am not sure of that. For sure lots of people have set their browsers to block third-party cookies.

So you have to tell your visitors to configure their browser to allow third-party cookies from `server.com`.

BTW, it is not safe to set a cookie on a redirect to a different domain. While it is allowed under the specification AFAIK, there have been issues with browser support. See, for example, this [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696204).

Comment: Thanks. I actually managed to solve this problem with a clue from Mavi Domates and other research I made by myself, before I saw your answer. So I decided to grant the bounty to Mavi, but I accepted your answer because it is more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `withCredentials` option when sending your ajax request to your http://server.com and your server.com should have the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to true.

```
Example code in Node.JS server:

var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

More on this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

```
Example code in Angular.JS client
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

const options = new RequestOptions({
  method: RequestMethod.Post,
  url: 'https://google.com',
  withCredentials: true
});
```

More on this here: https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions

**Also check this out**: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24283 - it looks like a particular version of Angular had problems with this flag, so unless you're using a more up-to-date version, you might need to set the header explicitly.

**The reasoning of this is, unless the server explicitly tells the client *"I will accept cookies (set previously on my domain) passed by another domain"* - accepting the cookies would be a security issue.** More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: I've updated the question. I use version 7.1 of angular. Is that a good version?

Comment: Is your cookie set to secure? Are you using https?

Comment: No, I am using http

Comment: Your updated code includes the withCredentials as a header. That's a request option which adds the header. Can you please use it correctly? (Check out the code sample that I've provided)

Comment: Also make sure your browser is set for setting third party cookies

Answer (score 0):

From Access-Control-Allow-Origin spec:
*For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard;*

Try to add specific domain to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field.

I think you should use proxy in angular angular app. For more info check this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md